# Is attempting mySQL injection illegal?

Tags: sql-injection, legal

I was testing an SQL injector I made in Java and the site I tested it on said 'Detected security breach attempt' blah blah blah. Is what I did illegal or not?
I have found different opinions and answers on different web pages and dont actually know.
(I live in the UK). If it is illegal, how serious is the crime?

Comment: This is highly dependent on the case, the affected party's willingness to press charges, your perceived intentions, the end result of your actions, how big of an #!@%hole the other affected party is, etc. All you need to know is that what you're doing is illegal, and is punishable by law. Only attempt those things on your machine inside on your network. In the UK, you'd be prosecuted under the  Computer Misuse Act. The punishment is a minimum of 6 months improvement or a 5k GBP fine.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, illegal because you are attempting to access information that you shouldn't have access to. Checkout the [Computer Misuse Act 1990](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Misuse_Act_1990).

> Sections 1-3 of the Act introduced three criminal offences
>
> - unauthorised access to computer material, punishable by 6 months' imprisonment or a fine "not exceeding level 5 on the standard scale" (currently £5000);

*Standard Internet Disclaimer: [IANAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANAL)*

Comment: Of course, this depends upon *where*. In the US it is illegal without permission. In Russia or China, it seems to be legal.

Comment: @atk: Exactly. The OP specified UK though, so that is where my answer is based.